# Salesforce Dynamic calculation

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I have a field called total amount in salesforce, which is price * quantity * (1-discount) and I want to play around with discount and quantity to see the different total amounts . How can I make the total amount field dynamic based on the values entered in the quantity and discount ?

These values are on the quote level where I go to line items and add products and play with the price and quantity of the different products. Ideally it would be nice to see the total final price too . How do i achieve this ?

I tried to create a javascript button but was not able to select that in my layout

Comment: What do you have in mind. Some onchange/onblur javascript in your custom(?) quote editor to give the user a feel of the value? (there might be rounding errors and some other hiccups) but generally it'd be instant as opposed to server round trip. Or do you want to submit to apex this "what if" and display the results back without actually saving whole thing on every change? Do you even have a custom page/aura/lwc for this or all standard?